# Button over clickable list element

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my webapp, I have a list that shows the user options. Each 'li' is clickable, so that the user can go to the selected option. Also, each li has 2 buttons one to delete and the other to edit. However, whenever I click on the edit or delete button, the li element onclick event is also fired. How can I prevent this?

```
<ul id="filters" class="nomargin">
 <li class="item" data-username="blub" onclick="alert('li clicked')"> 
  <span class="default-view">
   <span class="title">id5</span>
   <span class="control">
    <button class="edit-btn" value="edit" onclick="alert('edit')"></button>
    <button class="delete-btn" value="delete" onclick="alert('delete')"></button>
   </span>
  </span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I have a jsfiddle with a prototype of it: http://jsfiddle.net/LkUn9/

Comment: I'd stay clear of using inline-scripts within your html.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation();`

```
<ul id="filters" class="nomargin">
 <li class="item" data-username="blub" onclick="alert('li clicked')"> 
  <span class="default-view">
   <span class="title">id5</span>
   <span class="control">
    <button class="edit-btn" value="edit" onclick="alert('edit'); event.stopPropagation();"></button>
    <button class="delete-btn" value="delete" onclick="alert('delete'); event.stopPropagation();"></button>
   </span>
  </span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/LkUn9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event is fired from clicking on the `li` tag.

Is there any real purpose for having a click handler on the `li`? What functionality and purpose does it serve? If you have event handlers on the buttons, you **shouldn't** need another event handler attached to it's parent element. You could, but there's no real purpose, especially when you're just showing an alert. However, I can't imagine any real use for it, semantically or realistically for a website of any kind.

If you want to solve this, do the following with jQuery.

```
$('li.item').on('click', function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

or

```
$('li.item').on('click', function( event ) {

    event.stopPropagation();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop propagation of the click event on the button.

```
$('.edit-btn').click(function(event){
    alert('edit');
    return false;
};
```

Would be one way to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this is to stay away from using inline scripts.  It is best to add event listeners using the DOM to keep everything clean.  To answer the question, you can `return false;` to stop the event from propagating to the `li` element.

Similarly if you bind the event to the DOM, you can stop the propagation using the event object:

```
function myClickHandler(evt) {
    //do stuff
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use event.stopPropagation()

```
    <ul id="filters" class="nomargin">
        <li class="item" data-username="blub" onclick="clickLi()"> 
            <span class="default-view">
                <span class="title">id5</span>
                <span class="control">
                    <button class="edit-btn" value="edit" onclick="clickButton(event);">Edit</button>
                    <button class="delete-btn" value="delete" onclick="return clickButton(event);">Delete</button>
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        function clickButton(e){
            console.log(e);
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('button');
        }
        function clickLi(){
            console.log('li');
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing event.stopImmediatePropagation() as well as avoiding jQuery libraries and binding events on load:

http://jsfiddle.net/QFWN2/

```
function modify(el, e){
 alert(el.value);   
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();

}
```

and

```
<button class="edit-btn" value="edit" onclick="modify(this, event);"></button>
<button class="delete-btn" value="delete" onclick="modify(this, event);"></button>
```